# Trouble in using NativeProcess, actionscript3 to convert files

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a program to convert png files in ATF textures but i am having some trouble when i try to use the NativeProcess... I am using actionscript 3 with IntelliJ IDEA.

I want to pass that prompt command `png2atf -c p -i starling-atf.png -o starling.atf`, to my NativeProcess...

So, i choose a png file, from a `File().load` object, and then i want to take this file and send as a parameter to my `NativeProcess` and make the conversation over the prompt command (`png2atf -c p -i starling-atf.png -o starling.atf`)....

Any ideas?

Comment: You say you're having trouble... what is the trouble? Does it not work as expected or aren't you sure how to pass the file path as an argument at all?

Comment: What have you tried? My guess is that you need to pass a file path to the `png2atf` command, just like you would do in the command prompt.

Comment: @Antonie Lassauzay thats the problem, i cant pass the line command as a parameter...

Comment: @puggsoy i have this... <code>f = new File();
f.nativePath = "C:/projects/SDK/Adobe Gaming SDK 1.0.1/Utilities/ATF Tools/Windows/png2atf.exe";` ` var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
processArgs[0] = "-i ";
processArgs[1] = "C:/projects/images/Penguins.png";
processArgs[2] = " -o";
processArgs[3] = "C:/projects/images/Penguins.atf"
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;</code>

Comment: The code tag doesn't work here, click "help" below "Add Comment" to see how to write it. Anyway, this looks like valid code, so I don't see the problem. Please edit your question (not a comment) with the code you have tried to do what you want, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@puggsoy u are write, the problem were spaces... i put some spaces with the args, thats why..
here its the right code:



`f.nativePath = "C:/projects/SDK/Adobe Gaming SDK 1.0.1/Utilities/ATF Tools/Windows/png2atf.exe";`

```
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = f;

    // now create the arguments Vector to pass it to the executable file
    var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
    processArgs[0] = "-c";
    processArgs[1] = arg;
    processArgs[2] = "-i";
    processArgs[3] = input;
    processArgs[4] = "-o";
    processArgs[5] = output;
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
    process = new NativeProcess();
    process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```